# $C_0$-semigroups and shift operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $(X,\|\cdot \|_{sup})$ be a Banach space, where $X=\{\phi\in C[0,1]: \phi(1)=0\}$. Now, let $\{T(t)\}$ be the family of left translations, i.e. $(T(t)\phi)(x)=\phi(x+t)\cdot \chi_{x+t\le 1}$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $t\ge 0$. I want to prove that this family of operators is a strongly continuous semigroup and that the growth bound is $-\infty$.

I already proved that this set is a semigroup. So, in order to conclude that $\{T(t)\}$ is a $C_0$-semigroup I need to show that the function $t \mapsto T(t)\phi$ is continuous in $[0,1)$ with values in $X$, for each $\phi\in X$, however, I don't know how.

Secondly, I know that $\omega_0(T) :=
\inf\{\omega \in  \mathbb{R} : \exists M = M_\omega  \ge 1 \text{ such that } \|T(t)\| \le M_\omega e^{\omega t} \text{ for every } t \ge 0\}$, but how can I obtain $\omega_{T}=-\infty$. I tried to show that $\|T(t)\| \le M_\omega e^{\omega t}$ holds for all $\omega<0$.

How can I finish this proof? Any hints?

Comment: 1) $\phi$ is uniformly continuous. 2) What is $T(t)$ for $t \geqslant 1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $T(t)=0$ for $t>1$, but how can I use this fact? and I really don't see why $\phi$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: So the inequality $\lVert T(t)\rVert \leqslant M_\omega e^{\omega t}$ holds for $t \geqslant 1$ regardless of what $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M_\omega > 0$ you have. Thus you need only care about $t \in [0,1)$. What is $\lVert T(t)\rVert$ for $t \in [0,1)$?